# Fill out multiple columns in one dataset with data from another dataset

Tags: r, lookup

I am looking to fill out multiple columns in one dataset with values from another dataset.

I have two dataframes, df_1 and df_lookup.

df_1 looks like this:

```
  sub_id diag_1 diag_2 diag_3
1      1   S019   T028   S021
2      2   S520              
3      3   S320   S270   S324
4      4   S023          S109
5      5   S826   S420   S729
```

df_lookup looks like this:

```
  diag_map ais iss_br
1      S019   1      6
2      S020   3      6
3      S021   2      1
4      S025   1      1
5      S109   1      1
6      S110   5      2
7      S270   0      0
8      S320   0      0
9      S420   4      4
10     S520   2      5
11     S729   2      3
12     T028   1      0
```

I would like to match the diagnoses (diag_1, diag_2, diag_3) in df_1 with diag_map in df_lookup and insert the corresponding ais and iss_br from df_lookup into df_1 to get the following:

```
  sub_id diag_1 ais_1 iss_br_1 diag_2 ais_2 iss_br_2 diag_3 ais_3 iss_br_3
1      1   S019     1        6   T028     1        0   S021     2        1
2      2   S520     2        5                                            
3      3   S320     0        0   S270     0        0   S324  <NA>     <NA>
4      4   S023    NA       NA                         S109     1        1
5      5   S826    NA       NA   S420     4        4   S729     2        3
```

In my actual datasets there are many more rows (approx. 4000 in df_1 and 25000 in df_lookup).

Can anybody help me with a way to do this in R? Thanks!

Comment: do you want both empty strings `''` and `NA` in your result?

Comment: Preferably yes, but it is not strictly necessary. And thanks for answering, I will try it straight away :)

Comment: glad to have been of help.  Please accept the answer as per usual practice and for further reference on SO.  You can however accept only one answer per question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
df <- read.table(text = '  sub_id diag_1 diag_2 diag_3
1      1   S019   T028   S021
2      2   S520   ""  ""         
3      3   S320   S270   S324
4      4   S023   ""       S109
5      5   S826   S420   S729
', header = TRUE)

df_lookup <- read.table(header = T, text = "  diag_map ais iss_br
1      S019   1      6
2      S020   3      6
3      S021   2      1
4      S025   1      1
5      S109   1      1
6      S110   5      2
7      S270   0      0
8      S320   0      0
9      S420   4      4
10     S520   2      5
11     S729   2      3
12     T028   1      0")

library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(across(2:4, ~ df_lookup$ais[match(., df_lookup$diag_map)],
                .names = '{.col}_ais'),
         across(2:4, ~df_lookup$iss_br[match(., df_lookup$diag_map)],
         .names = '{.col}_iss_br'))
#>   sub_id diag_1 diag_2 diag_3 diag_1_ais diag_2_ais diag_3_ais diag_1_iss_br
#> 1      1   S019   T028   S021          1          1          2             6
#> 2      2   S520                        2         NA         NA             5
#> 3      3   S320   S270   S324          0          0         NA             0
#> 4      4   S023          S109         NA         NA          1            NA
#> 5      5   S826   S420   S729         NA          4          2            NA
#>   diag_2_iss_br diag_3_iss_br
#> 1             0             1
#> 2            NA            NA
#> 3             0            NA
#> 4            NA             1
#> 5             4             3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```r
sub_id <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
diag_1 <- c('S019', 'S520', 'S320', 'S023', 'S826')
diag_2 <- c('T028', NA, 'S270', NA, 'S420')
diag_3 <- c('S021', NA, 'S324', 'S109', 'S729')
df_1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(sub_id, diag_1, diag_2, diag_3))

diag_map <- c('S019', 'S020', 'S021', 'S025', 'S109', 'S110', 
              'S270', 'S320', 'S420', 'S520', 'S729', 'T028')
ais <- c(1,3,2,1,1,5,0,0,4,2,2,1)
iss_br <- c(6,6,1,1,1,2,0,0,4,5,3,0)
df_lookup <- as.data.frame(cbind(diag_map, ais, iss_br))


library(dplyr)
join1 <- select(left_join(df_1, df_lookup, by = c("diag_1" = "diag_map")), sub_id, diag_1, ais, iss_br)
join2 <- select(left_join(df_1, df_lookup, by = c("diag_2" = "diag_map")), diag_2, ais, iss_br)
join3 <- select(left_join(df_1, df_lookup, by = c("diag_3" = "diag_map")), diag_3, ais, iss_br)
final <- cbind(join1, join2, join3)
colnames(final) <- c('sub_id', 'diag_1', 'ais_1', 'iss_br_1', 'diag_2', 'ais_2', 'iss_br_2', 'diag_3', 'ais_3', 'iss_br_3')
print(final)

> final
  sub_id diag_1 ais_1 iss_br_1 diag_2 ais_2 iss_br_2 diag_3 ais_3 iss_br_3
1      1   S019     1        6   T028     1        0   S021     2        1
2      2   S520     2        5   <NA>  <NA>     <NA>   <NA>  <NA>     <NA>
3      3   S320     0        0   S270     0        0   S324  <NA>     <NA>
4      4   S023  <NA>     <NA>   <NA>  <NA>     <NA>   S109     1        1
5      5   S826  <NA>     <NA>   S420     4        4   S729     2        3
```

There are probably more autonomous approaches to this problem but here is a rough reproducible example.